# Absolute Url returnUrl asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a central page that logs on to other sites .

I would like to get an absolute return URL.

For example, currently I am getting `/Message/ShowMsg/514` and I want to get `www.exampele.com/Message/ShowMsg/514`

I use authentication forms.

Comment: What version of .Net / MVC are you using?

Comment: what do you mean by get? Do you want to get the complete URL in your code? Did you try `Request.Url.OriginalString` or `Request.RawUrl`?

Comment: MVC 5.2.3.0. 
I have a login page "www.example.com".
And another page of the forum "www.example2.com."
By accessing the page "www.example.com/message/Message/ShowMsg/514"
I am redirected to the login "www.example.com" and gets the return url "/ Message / showmsg / 514". but I want to get the link "www.example2.com/message/Message/ShowMsg/514"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use Url.Action

```
Url.Action("showMsg", "Message", new {id = 514},HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
```

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme` - it will return `www.example.com`

Comment: only to have to change the other applications. Can I do this by changing just something in my logging application?